# Unity Mathf.Lerp only executes ones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Fire(float firingRate)
{
    TimePerFrame += Time.deltaTime;
    if(TimePerFrame >= firingRate)
    {
        Vector3 ProjectileDistance = new Vector3(0, 30, 0); //distance between center of the campion and it's head
        GameObject beam = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position + ProjectileDistance, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        beam.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(0, projectileSpeed, 0);
        //  AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(fireSound, transform.position);
        TimePerFrame = 0;
    }
}

void Update ()
{
    if (freezePosition == false)
    {
        Fire(firingRate);
        PositionChaning();
        firingRate = Mathf.Lerp(minFiringRate, maxFiringRate, 0.1f);
        Debug.Log(firingRate);
    }
}
```

I want my firerate to be flexible, i want it to start by shooting fast and let it automatically lower it's fire rate. (the bigger the firingRate float is the slower the speed is)

The problem is that `firingRate = Mathf.Lerp(minFiringRate, maxFiringRate, 0.1f);` 
triggers once and only once. It doesn't seem to change it's value every frame.

`Debug.Log(firingRate);` tells the value every frame but it seems to remain a constant.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update triggers every Frame, and so does your `Mathf.Lerp` However you are not changing the interpolation, which in your case is defined as `0.1f`.

By changing this interpolation, you will be able to achieve the 'shifting' of fire rate.

In your case you could define a variable `t` outside the scope of your update, and update it inside the `Update()` through `t += 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;`

The [Mathf.Lerp documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) has a pretty good sample of how todo so as well

```
void Update()
{
    // animate the position of the game object...
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(minimum, maximum, t), 0, 0);

    // .. and increate the t interpolater
    t += 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;

    // now check if the interpolator has reached 1.0
    // and swap maximum and minimum so game object moves
    // in the opposite direction.
    if (t > 1.0f)
    {
        float temp = maximum;
        maximum = minimum;
        minimum = temp;
        t = 0.0f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
firingRate = Mathf.Lerp(minFiringRate, maxFiringRate, 0.1f);
```

As you can see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) your `t` has to be calculated every frame.

```
public static float Lerp(float a, float b, float t);
```

You can change it like this:

```
private float fireTimer = 1.0f;
public float fireLimiter = 0.05f;

void Fire(float firingRate)
{
    TimePerFrame += Time.deltaTime;
    if(TimePerFrame >= firingRate)
    {
        Vector3 ProjectileDistance = new Vector3(0, 30, 0); //distance between center of the campion and it's head
        GameObject beam = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position + ProjectileDistance, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        beam.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(0, projectileSpeed, 0);
        //  AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(fireSound, transform.position);
        TimePerFrame = 0;
    }
}

void Update ()
{
    if (freezePosition == false)
    {
        if(fireTimer > 0.0f){
            fireTimer -= Time.deltaTime * fireLimiter;
        }
        Fire(firingRate);
        PositionChaning();
        firingRate = Mathf.Lerp(minFiringRate, maxFiringRate, fireTimer);
        Debug.Log(firingRate);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to reset `fireTimer` to `1.0f` after shooting!
The delay of the firerate can be controlled by `fireLimiter`

Comment: Thanks, i should've read the documentation before posting this